# new approach of indexing in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to define a new approach of indexing in Elasticsearch so i will edit tf idf method .
where to find TF-IDF elasticsearch implementation?
what are the packages in elasticsearch source code that i need to manipulate to implement the new approach?

Answer (score 1):

The TF/IDF similarity algorithm is implemented in Lucene, however, there are ways to define another similarity algorithm to be used inside Elasticsearch via the [similarity module](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-similarity.html). In addition to TF/IDF, there are currently [7 more similarities](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-similarity.html#_available_similarities) supported:

- BM25
- Classic similarity
- DFR similarity
- DFI similarity
- IB similarity
- LM Dirichlet similarity
- LM Jelinek Mercer similarity

Each of them has different parameters that you can tune. Maybe it'd be a good idea to test each of them before venturing into creating your own.

More info about the available Lucene similarity algorithms: https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_5_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/Similarity.html

Comment: after testing these similarities ,i want to create a custom similarity with just editing the BM25 algorithm .is it necessary to create a java plugin ?any idea to do that